# On duplicate a particular column, insert into database - Mysqlite

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am facing a problem with my database columns. 
*I have a column called "id" in my table ( I don't want to put primary key or make it unique).
Table Structure:

```
 x----x--------x------x------x
 | id | unique | name | phone|
 x----x--------x------x------x
 | 12 |  ab1   | Jhon |989898|
 x----x--------x------x------x
 | 13 |  cv12  | Nasn |983984|
 x----x--------x------x------x
```

I am receiving rows data from a PHP file,
Now I want to insert into this table by renaming the "id" if any row with the same "id" (Already Existing "id") is received by my PHP.

Comment: so,you want to check id before you insert and if id is already exist then you want to change id value to maximum id value from table right?

Comment: Yup! That's what I exactly want, but reading the table and comparing the id each time may lead to a very large number of codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query 1: `select count(*) from yourtable where id=<newrecord_id>`

if

```
result of  above query return 0 then you can simply insert new record
```

Else

```
 You need to find max value from table be below query
  select max(id) from yourtable;
  Now with new maximum id value + 1 = new id for insert new redord.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to put an unique constraint on that column you'll have to query the table for values matching that id first and then, after possibly changing it several times, insert it.

It not hard but you'll end up doing lots of queries. Sure, if you put (none unique) indexes on it those queries could be fast.

I would still put a primary key on the id column since that seems to be whats really correct. When getting a "duplicate key" error back from an insert you'll increment the id and retry until it works.

Comment: How do I get duplicate key error ?? And how should I process ??

Comment: If you have a unique index you'll get a duplicate key exception when that constraint is violated. It depends on your way of calling mysql how you get it.